# Erroneous message pops up in close dialog

Tags: bug, status-norepro, vote-to-close

I try to vote to close a question, but am greeted with this error message:

[image: "You may only load the close dialog every 3 seconds]

So I patiently wait until 3 seconds have passed, try again, and get the same error, over and over again. What is wrong here?

Comment: No repro for me...

Comment: Is your mouse okay? Is it triple clicking?

Comment: @Oli yes, my mouse is working fine. Just checked it, there are no unwanted multiple clicks.

Comment: try another question? still happening?

Comment: It's gone now. So this is one of those "went away on its own"-meta-questions.